# Cloud hosting for an small internal application

Tags: azure, cloud

I am about to start a new project which will have 4-5 users and will be for internal use only.

I am thinking about developing this in .NET and sql server for the database.

In regards to creating the application in the cloud using the technologies it seems expensive (windows). Linux seems to be cheaper but obviously restricted to other languages.

If i go down the .NET route i would need to get a sql server licence which aren't cheap i believe.

Could someone point me in the right direction in regards to good cloud providers?

I have looked into Azure, and Rackspace and are quite expensive when it comes to managed servers. But as the application does not to be scaleable i might have a bit more flexibility.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into `Windows Azure Websites` (http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/services/web-sites/)? For really simple and no-frills web applications, this is really an interesting proposition. Plus if you don't really care for custom domains and stuff, you could host it for free (http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/details/web-sites/)!

Answer (score 0):

Adding onto what Gaurav has already mentioned, from the SQL database perspective, Azure provides a managed SQL experience via its SQL Azure offering.  The database is pretty cheap - $10/month for a gig of space.  For a small internal application, if you don't care to have your own custom domain on the URL, all you would need is a free Azure website and a few bucks a month for the SQL Azure database.

If you happen to have an MSDN subscription, then there is a bunch of free Azure usage that's provided as a part of it to subscribers

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you need a SQL database? If you go the NoSql route by using Azure storage (tables, queues, and blobs) the costs are super cheap. Combine that with Azure web sites, which are also free or very low cost, your internal app may cost pennies per day.

See the Azure pricing calculator here: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/

Azure Storage: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/services/storage/

Azure Web Sites: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/services/web-sites/